# What is Untitled Document~ listing in an empy folder?

Tags: linux, debian

I'm new to Linux and studying it on Debian. When I list a director with ls command. I get a Untitled Document~ listing. I was wondering what it means?

Comment: Probably made by some auto-backup of some office software (LibreOffice, AbiWord, OpenOffice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, a filename ending in a `~` (such as `Untitled Document~`) is a hidden backup file (you can't see it in the normal file browser). You must have had an `Untitled Document` in the folder at one point. You can safely delete the file, if you no longer need the contents.

Answer (score 2):

Many Unix and GNU/Linux editors adds `~` sign to the file name of the backup copy of currently edited file. This is one of such files. You have edited some document or created new and it's backup copy still in your directory.

If you don't know what the file type it is. Use

```
file 'Untitled Document~'
```

to find out.